# How to get rid of red underlines in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I do not know how to get rid the red underlines in PyCharm IDE? How to resolve this tackle?

[image]

Comment: What does it says when you hover over it?

Comment: Use language injection.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use it but you can disable it right of the top.

[image: Click for image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html,

Here is the part that may help you

> Disable an inspection in the editor﻿

> Place the caret at the highlighted line and press Alt+Enter (or click the Intention action icon to use the intention action).

> Click the arrow next to the inspection you want to disable, and select Disable inspection.